# SQL Injection Prevention - Single Line Methods?

Tags: sql, postgresql, escaping, preg-replace, filter-var

I'll try to keep this one short and simple, using the example code below. Do you see this being a problem for any form of SQL-Injection...??

```
$tmpVar = isset($_POST['somePostVar']) ? pg_escape_string(utf8_encode(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i', '', filter_var($_POST['somePostVar'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)))) : 'error';
```

While i understand there maybe some over kill/redundant using all four methods.. I'd still rather be safe than sorry hence asking on here.

This resulting variable is to be used as

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE someCol='$tmpVar'
```

Now i know there are duplicate questions like this one around, I DO understand that and while not being a major poster on StackOverFlow... Daily browser and use i am...

So using pg_escape_string, utf8_encode, preg_replace and filter_var... this string is only limited to alphanumeric with underscores.. **Could it be broken easily with a form of SQL Injection**

utf8_encode is also here because postgresql can have issues when using pg_escape_string.. So they go hand in hand in this case.

Comment: Please understand I do know what each function does and some might be overkilling the string.. but there situations that need to be thought of in which a a simple fix is not always as easy as it seems... the question was can this particular string still be broken with a injection...

Answer (score 4):

Why would you make all this mess?

Just use parameterized queries like everyone else. See [PHP's manual on SQL injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and [bobby-tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com/).

You need to *understand* the problem, not just throw more layers of random half-understood things at it. `filter_var(..., FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)` for example is completely wrong to use with SQL, why would you possibly do that after you looked at [the documentation for it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)?

And why are you messing with the text encoding? You should not need to if `client_encoding` is correct.

---

If you're doing things like substituting identifiers, or other things where you cannot use server side query parameters, all you have to do is double any double quotes, so:

```
this "identifier" name
```

becomes:

```
"this ""identifier"" name"
```

per the SQL standard. PHP appears to provide the convenience function [`pg_escape_identifier`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-identifier.php) for this.

Similarly, with `standard_conforming_strings` enabled (default), quotes are doubled in literals, if you must supply them without using parameters, e.g. in `ALTER USER ... PASSWORD ...` and other places Pg doesn't support server side parameters. However, the PHP driver may still support client side parameters for these, so you can probably just use parameterized queries like normal, and if not, it's better to use PHP's [`pg_escape_literal`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-literal.php).

Comment: You should read up about using pg_escape_string and the problems it can cause for a postgres db which has utf8 encoding.

Comment: As for simply adding double quotes and expecting this to make a user adjustable query safe.... that is not safe...

Comment: @Mayhem If PHP requires you to mess with changing your text encodings when using these functions, it's even more broken than usual, or your `client_encoding` is misconfigured. I'd like to see a proper report that documents this issue in a reasonable level of detail. If you're just referring to a 6-year-old comment on the docs that doesn't explain its reasoning, that's not really much to go on, and mostly suggests `client_encoding` doesn't match the default PHP encoding.

Comment: The client side i will not have control over in certain environments and the server is still to be explored for this project. the above code / pseudo is a combination of testing and exploring options depending on the input/post data which it receives. While the title is not the best for the question. The question still remains about covering all extreme cases in the way of unknown setups on both ends.. This could be php,sql versions / limited extensions and so on,  also not referring to the one on php.net for 'pg_escape_string'. I do search around when i encounter a problem

Comment: @Mayhem The answer is really simple. Use parameterized queries. You are done.

Comment: Not every thing is that simple Craig, If you simply think using "parameter" type queries is the answer.. Well yea, Thanks for the personal insight though.